# ModernHttpClient in Xam Forms. Is it necessary in latest releases?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, httpclient

Most recommendations call for using ModernHttpClient in ios and android, including xam forms.  But HttpClient is in system.net in Xamarin Forms for all platforms now.  So is ModernHttpClient still a necessity?  Got links on the "why" of ModernHttpClient over system.net.httpclient ?  Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope I can shed some light into this! I still suggest using ModernHTTPClient. The difference between ModernHTTPClient and the .NET implementation is that ModernHTTPClient actually wraps the native HTTP handler in a .NET friendly syntax. This provides access to items such as TLS 1.2 support, which Mono currently does not directly support[1].

There are also some performance gains to be had by using ModernHTTPClient, as again the native implementations are used "under the hood".

I hope this clears up the differences somewhat. Thanks!

[1]
The latest version of Xamarin.iOS does allow for Apple TLS to be used, however this does not apply to Android

Comment: You can use the `XA_HTTP_CLIENT_HANDLER_TYPE` on `Xamarin.Android` in order to use the "native"  `java.net.URLConnection` @  https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/transport-layer-security/#Xamarin.Android

Comment: got some links to perf gains and such?  trying to find 'hard doc'.  counldn't dig out much, figured i'm missing something out there.

Comment: The only real hard doc I could find was the main page for the library: http://log.paulbetts.org/fast-http-with-modernhttpclient/ and my experience regarding performance improvements are anecdotal, I do not have a controlled test

Comment: Xamarin cycle 8  now has an option to use "AndroidClientHandler" in an Android project.

Comment: Fresh info here: https://blog.xamarin.com/securing-web-requests-with-tls-1-2/. Note the section for Android that shows programatically how you can let the project default implementation be used (may or may not be TLS 1.2 depending on your settings) or the newer AndroidClientHandler metioned by Louis.